# External rewrite rules missing in htaccess - Multisite

Tags: multisite, redirect, htaccess, wp-redirect

I'm trying to set up some external redirects, but it seems like they are not being added to htacccess even tho it's supposed to (I think).

```php
add_rewrite_rule('^dashboard\/([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$', ZPB_P_PATH_URI . '/inc/dashboard/dist/$matches[1]', 'top');
```

I know that it's supposed to work because I did it in the past on another Wordpress, but the only thing that differs is that the site is a multisite, and I'm wondering if I miss something

I tried to call `save_mod_rewrite_rules()` but it's seems to be undefined.

[EDIT]

So after checking the content of `save_mod_rewrite_rules()` there is a check if the site is a multisite:

```php
if ( is_multisite() ) {
    return;
}
```

So for now I don't know how to handle this, I really need a way to control htaccess because the htaccess isn't in our git, so the only way I can do it is to copy a small portion of the function that handles the writing process in htaccess and include it in my code :/

If someone has an idea ...

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite rules are not added to htaccess by default: they are recorded in the options table, under the option name `rewrite_rules`. That option is checked every time WP runs `parse_request`.

If your rewrites aren't working as expected I'd look elsewhere for the cause (incorrect regex, rules in wrong order, rules being added too late etc).